# I want to give green and red color for image areas

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, imagemap

I want to show status with 0 area as red dot and status with 1 area are green. I used style tag for area. But not color coming on image area. Anybody knows please help me. I am sharing my code below

```
   <html>
   <map name="map1" id="_map1">
            <?php  
            foreach ($points as $point)
            {
                $name=$point->name;
                $status=$point->status;
                if($status==1){ ?>
                    <area shape="rect" coords="10,15,18,20"  href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/green.jpg"   alt="" title="" onmouseover="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
                <?php 
                }
                else if($status==0) {?>
                    <area shape="rect"  coords="0,0,50,50" href="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/red.jpg"   alt="" title="" onmouseover="<?php echo $name; ?>"/> 
                <?php 
                } 
            } ?>
   </map>
   <img id="map1" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/rectangle.png" usemap="#map1" border="0" width="800" height="600" alt="" />
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example use of `<map>` [Html map tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

The `href` attribute does not show the image (red or green). It is a hyperlink to the target image. The image displays on the screen is the `src` file of the `<img>` tag.

You may need to generate the image dynamically on the server side, or use `<canvas>` to render the data on the client side.

Comment: can i give color to area tag?? its not coming

Comment: I don't think you can set the color for `<area>` tag.
If you only use the `rect` shape, the `<div>` with some CSS style should work.